# Microsoft Graph - Java; AuthorizationCodeProvider : how to get the "authorizationCode"

Tags: java, authentication, oauth-2.0, authorization, microsoft-graph-api

I'm using [msgraph-sdk-java-auth](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-java-auth) through an application that I've created.
I'm trying to get data from Microsoft Azure with the object `AuthorizationCodeProvider` but I'm not able to understand how to get the `AUTHORIZATION_CODE`parameter.

Somebody knows how to use this class?

Thanks!

Comment: Hello Timscht, please provide some code where the AUTHORIZATION_CODE is required, so people can better help with your exact problem

Comment: Hi thanks, for the reply. There is not a lot of code from the doc, the only thing I've got is this `AuthorizationCodeProvider authProvider = new AuthorizationCodeProvider(CLIENT_ID, SCOPES, AUTHORIZATION_CODE, REDIRECT_URL, NATIONAL_CLOUD, TENANT, CLIENT_SECRET);`
Then we use it for getting a client graph

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, `AUTHORIZATION_CODE` is the Authorization Code received from the initial authorize call. You could find the authorization_code in the **Steps to get authorizationCode** from the [sample](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-java-auth#41-authorization-code-provider).

[image]